# Codeigniter executing a hook with database calls prior to main Model constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I've been using hooks for my database migrations in my CI app using the `post_controller_constructor` hook.

In my recent revisions, I've changed my main Model variables from being set within the class constructor to being loaded from a db table. When I attempt to execute my new migration with the `DB Forge` data in it, my model doesn't load because it gets hung up on the fact that the table doesn't exist yet.

So I obviously can't make any database calls using `pre_controller` because I have no access to the main CI object. `post_controller_constructor` seems to execute after my Model constructor is loaded. What can I do to grab from the database before my Model is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do it in the actual constructor (before calling `parent::__construct()`)?  I don't see the need for hooks in this case.

Comment: I was thinking about just going this route. Hooks seemed to be a nice clean approach but I don't it was designed for what I want to do.

Comment: Extending the `CI_Model` class is probably the better approach in this case.

Comment: Where at, in my hook class?

Comment: Create a new file: application/core/MY_Model.php.  Define a class `MY_Model`, which extends `CI_Model`.  Do your migration checks in the constructor (before calling `parent::__construct()`)

Comment: Well, part of my issue was that I was auto-loading my main Model, which apparently loads prior to the `post_controller_constructor` hook. Either way, I decided to go with this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744750/1133306. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  CI hooks feel a little underdeveloped if you ask me.

Comment: Agreed - they could at least expand on the docs a bit. Currently it's very obscure.