# Migrations Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, database-migration

As seen on "[How do I run CodeIgniter migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154065/how-do-i-run-codeigniter-migrations#11744750)" I created the following migration controller:

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->input->is_cli_request()
        or exit("Execute via command line: php index.php migrate");

        $this->load->library('migration');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!$this->migration->latest())
        {
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        }
    }
}
```

And the following migration script under `migrations/001_CreateUserTable`:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_CreateUserTable extends CI_Migration
{
    private $table='user';

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field('id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT')
                    ->add_field('username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL')
                    ->add_field('password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL');
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id',true);
        $this->dbforge->create_table($this->table);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table($this->table);
    }
}
```

But when I run on my command line interface:

```
php index.php migrate
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR: An Error Was Encountered
>
> Migrations has been loaded but is disabled or set up incorrectly.

Do you have any sort of idea hot to fix it?

## Edit 1

On `application/config` I set the `$config['migration_enabled']=true;` value still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following:

REMOVE the `$config['migration_enabled']=true;` from `application/config.php` and chance it from `application/migration.php`

Also change the `$config['migration_type']` from `timestamp` to `sequential`, set the `$config['migration_version']` into `'001'`, also change the `$config['migration_auto_latest']` from `application/migration.php` too.

*NOTE:*
When using enviromental/fastcgi parameters use the `env` UNIX command in order to execute the php via cli.