# How to Run / Add migrations using Eloquent in CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, codeigniter-3

How do you add Migrations and run them in CodeIgniter using Eloquent?
 
I found a nice tutorial (not in English) how to add Eloquent to CodeIgniter. But when he shows the migrations folder.. I'm not sure how it was added. Can someone help?

In the Video Eloquent is added to Codeigniter using Composer.json. And then he setup Eloquent in application/config.php and application/database.php . But I'm curious how migrations is setup.

Video Link: https://youtu.be/t6dI8T9Znhw?t=257

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run CodeIgniter migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154065/how-do-i-run-codeigniter-migrations)

Comment: Not really. My question is how to Add Phinx Migrations. Not CI3 default migrations. I think alot of Laravel (Eloquent) methods are really nice. But Laravel is abit bloated and using just some packages would be nice.